# Aligning child div vertically instead of relative to parent div's content

Tags: css

My issue is with aligning the right content box (which displays the user list) at the top of the parent div, which is class Content-Row. The left content box and right content box are inside 'Content-Row'.

I have tried using the vertical-align css property, and tried switching display to grid, grid is behaving the same as flex.

[image: screenshot]

```
  .Content-Row {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .Content-Box-Right {
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.contentBox.background};
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: ${({ theme }) => theme.contentBox.shadow};
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .Content-Box-Left {
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.contentBox.background};
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: ${({ theme }) => theme.contentBox.shadow};
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Content-Row {
    ...
    align-items: flex-start;
    ...
}
```

Aligning the items to the start of the flexbox when it is `flex-direction: row;` (which is default) should get you what you want.

Comment: That did not work for me, I achieved it by using absolute and defining specific top/left/right numbers, and with a conditional in my react html code, but I do not think this is the best implementation.

Comment: Here's an example. Maybe this will help. https://codepen.io/mattbontrager/pen/abqmoWp